# confirmation email as a Data Element Type - Function Points

Tags: software-design, measure, code-complexity, function-points

I understand that a confirmation message on a UI is counted as a Data Element Type (DET). What if my confirmation message is an alert box on a UI plus an email confirmation.

Should i count it as 1 DET or 2 DETs

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it counts as 2 DET's since I can't think of a way it could be seen as a single one:

- the user is notified in two completly different ways.
- the software needs to check both confirmations, the input actually consits of two data elements.
- According to [this](http://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/5/7.4/) a DET is to decide if this data element is required and this can possibly differ.

But I'm not an IT professor, this is only the logical value.

Comment: I agree.  A UI Confirmation (alone) would be counted as a DET.  An email confirmation (alone) would be counted as a DET.  Therefore using both counts as two.  BTW, for what it's worth I have taught computer science course so I guess I am an IT Professor. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely count as 2 DETs. The UI alert box is a different feature from the email confirmation.